# VBA to find Specific text in a range of columns

Tags: vba, macros

I have value as "TRUE" in columns B to H. I want my macro to return "FALSE" in column A if any of the cell in range B:H contains "FALSE" else "TRUE". And do it until the last filled row. Any help is appreciated!

I tried below code which is working for one row but how to do it for all the filled rows?

```
Sub Test2()

Dim foundRng As Range

Set foundRng = Range("B2:H2").Find("FALSE")

If foundRng Is Nothing Then
    Range("A2").Value = "TRUE"
Else
    Range("A2").Value = "FALSE"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! What have you tried? [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1789855/edit) your question, include you code and indicates problem with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code and included:

- A variable to find the last non-empty cell of column A: `Dim lastRow As Long`.
- Then, use a loop to check the value of B:H range and displays the result on the corresponding row of column A.

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim foundRng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    'Find the last row with data of column A -- A is indicated with 1
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Loop from row 2 to the last row
    For counter = 2 To lastRow
        'Check the value based on the row
        Set foundRng = Range("B" & counter & ":H" & counter).Find("FALSE")
        
        If foundRng Is Nothing Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & counter).Value = "TRUE"
        Else
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & counter).Value = "FALSE"
        End If
        
    Next counter
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it fills for all the rows however, only the outcome of first row (A2) is getting replicated to all the cells in down. I want the condition to be applied for each row.

Comment: @Rax that's not what you wrote on your question ("I want my macro to return "FALSE" in column A if any of the cell in range B:H contains "FALSE" else "TRUE") and not what your code is doing. The code is returning false if a single false is found, and returning true if the range B2:H2 are true as asked in your question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I think I need to declare Set foundRng in such a way that outcome for each row is dependednt on the values found in the same rows. For A2 it looks in B2:H2, for A3 it looks in B3:H3...and so on. Something like below. Please help.

Comment: @Rax You can do via a loop.

Comment: How to use Loop. Sorry but I am new to VBA.

Comment: @Rax I have modified the code. See edit to my answer. Note that if the question has been successfully answered, you can mark it as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Yes, working great! You made my day !!!